# Get object type and use in generic method call

Tags: c#, generics

I  have a generic method to deal with importing various object types from Quickbooks.

```
public ActionConfirmation<int> Import<TEntity>(List<TEntity> lstEntityModifiedSinceLastSync, FinancialsSyncJobQueue currentJobQEntry, FinancialsSyncSession session, 
    FinancialsIntegrationContext financialsIntegrationContext) 
    where TEntity : class, IEntity, IAuditStamps, IFinancials, new()
```

Today I use a `switch` statement to invoke the above generic method with the correct type:

```
switch (enumDataElement)
{
    case DataElement.Account:
        {
            //Parse QB query response and convert to Stratus Chart of Accounts object list
            var lstAccountsModifiedSinceLastSync = QuickbooksChartOfAccounts.ParseQueryResponse(response, session);

            importResult = importService.Import<FinancialsChartOfAccount>(lstAccountsModifiedSinceLastSync, 
                currentJobQEntry, session, financialsIntegrationContext);

            break;
        }
    case DataElement.Item:
        {
            var lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync = QuickbooksItem.ParseQueryResponse(response, session);

            importResult = importService.Import<Item>(lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync, 
                currentJobQEntry, session, financialsIntegrationContext);

            break;
        }
        etc...
}
```

I'd like to clean this up a little, pull the importService.Import call out of the switch statement and put it at the end and do something like:

```
Type entityType = lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync.FirstOrDefault().GetType();
importResult = importService.Import<entityType>(lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync, 
    currentJobQEntry, session, financialsIntegrationContext);
```

But I can't seem to get that to work. Error is: `The type or namespace could not be found...`

Comment: @EdPlunkett - Thank you for pointing me to that question/answer. I didn't see that the way I was searching for existing questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because type arguments are the actual names of types, resolved at compile time by the compiler. It needs the name of a type, but you're giving it the name of a variable instead.

```
Type entityType = lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync.FirstOrDefault().GetType();
importResult = importService.Import<entityType>(lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync, 
    currentJobQEntry, session, financialsIntegrationContext);
```

It is possible to call generic methods with type parameters determined at runtime, [but you have to use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/424129). For your case, something like this (not tested):

```
//  Get the entity type by reflection too, so we don't have to worry about
//  crashing on an empty list. 
Type entityType = lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First();

MethodInfo method = importService.GetType().GetMethod("Import");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);

generic.Invoke(importService, new object[] { 
        lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync, 
        currentJobQEntry, 
        session, 
        financialsIntegrationContext
    });
```

It's up to you whether you consider this more or less ugly than what you've got already. And if `Import` has overloads, you'll have to rummage through a list of `MethodInfo` objects to find the right one.

By the way, you could also use type information on `lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync` to get *its* type parameter, instead of relying on there being an item in the list. If there's not, `FirstOrDefault()` will return null and that line will throw an exception.

Comment: thanks for the pointer on getting the type of the list...but I thought that'd return a type of List<Type> instead of just Type, which I didn't think would work. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @ChadRichardson It will return the type of List<Type> -- you'll have to look at `lstItemsModifiedSinceLastSync.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First()`. Since List<T> is List<T>, you can safely assume there's exactly one of them.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the clarity.